# SQL Server column/table names breaks (i.e. splits) on its own when the SP is called from the ASP.net application

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Today I faced a strange issue, I am not even sure if it’s genuinely an issue.

Issue: occasionally, the column and / or table names were automatically breaking down when my ASP.Net application called the stored procedure which contains the column / table name mentioned in it.

For ex, a column `MasterKeyID` was used in the stored procedure. When this stored procedure was called from the .Net application, the application threw error saying: couldn’t find object ‘MasterKey’.

I don’t have any object (table or column) with this name. I double checked and triple checked it.

Has this ever happened to anybody else?

Comment: Does the stored procedure use dynamic SQL (That is, constructing strings and then running them using `EXEC` or `sp_executesql`)? If so, it might be making a mistake when constructing the string and truncating the name.

Comment: 90% of the time this is user error for me.  I find that I am not calling what I think I am.  You can try to trace the sql query coming in to your db to ensure that is what is happening.